# Zurb Foundation: Nav Bar disappears for small range of screen sizes

Tags: css, html, sass, zurb-foundation

I recently started using Foundation and figured it out for the most part. [Here is the site I'm having trouble with.](http://musiciansgeneralstore.com)

HTML CODE

```
 <nav class="tab-bar show-for-medium-down">
      <section class="left-small">
        <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#off-canvas-navigation"><span></span></a>
        <section>
      </nav>
      <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
          <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li class="navFont"><a href="index.html">MUSICIAN'S GENERAL STORE</a></li>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nemc.com/musicians-general-store-inc/brass-instruments/">Instrument Rental</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="press.html">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.musiciansgeneralstore.tumblr.com">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>

              </ul>
            <li class="navFont"><a href="metropolis.html">METROPOLIS PRODUCTIONS</a></li>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="metband.html">Metropolis Entertainment Band</a></li>
                <li><a href="production.html">Live Audio + Production</a></li>
                <li><a href="referrals.html">Stage + Backline Rental</a></li>
              </ul>
            <li class="navFont"><a href="rockscool.html">ROCK'SCOOL</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
                <li><a href="instruments_rates.html">Instruments & Rates</a></li>
                <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="teachers.html">Teachers</a></li>

            </li>
              </ul>


            </li>

            <li class="navFont"><a href="#" data-reveal-id="modalContact" data-animation="fade">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
        <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

    <!-- Desktop Navigation-->
    <div class="fixed hide-for-medium-down">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
      <ul class="title-area padding-logo">
        <li class="name"><a href="#"><img class="padding-top-20" src="img/thumblogos/mgs.png" width="75px"></a></li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul>
          <li class="navFont active"><a href="index.html">MUSICIAN'S GENERAL STORE</a></li>
          <li class="navFont"><a href="metropolis.html">METROPOLIS PRODUCTIONS</a></li>
          <li class="navFont"><a href="rockscool.html">ROCK'SCOOL</a></li>
          <li class="navFont"><a href="#" data-reveal-id="modalContact" data-animation="fade">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="social">
           <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/musiciansgeneralstore"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.musiciansgeneralstore.tumblr.com"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:info@musiciansgeneralstore.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>

    </nav>
  </div><!--/fixed class-->
  <!-- CONTENT START -->
```

Unfortunately, the nav bar doesn't show up for certain screen sizes (width of 1025 - 1345px). Mobile/tablet and large desktop screens look great, but on some cheaper/smaller desktop screens the resolution triggers the nav bar to disappear without the mobile menu popping up.

I've tried to find a solution to this through several different forums and have come up with nothing. Any ideas on how I can force the desktop menu to show up until the resolution is small enough to trigger tablet/mobile?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu is too wide to fit in that width range, so the menu is in fact overflowing.

[image]

My advice? Add a media query for that size range where your shrink the padding a bit in the navbar.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1350px){
    .top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button), .top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button){
        padding: 0 10px;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}
```